# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, android-support-design

I have bellow `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarMainActivity"
                style="@style/CustomToolbar"
                android:background="@color/biscay"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/icon_drawer_imagebutton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_drawer_imagebutton">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/icon_logo_imagebutton"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_logo"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_logo"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo_white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/nameUniversity_textview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_logo_imagebutton"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/nameUniversity"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextLight"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsMainActivity"
            style="@style/CustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpagerMainActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabsMainActivity"
            android:background="@color/colorTextLight" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Navigation Drawer-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/gallery" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my library is:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

But get me bellow error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're using `AndroidX` tags-components which you already have `AppCompat` dependencies. This will cause other issues too. Go with the `Refactor -> Migrate to AndoridX` and add the mentioned dependency for the material components too.

In your `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

It's coming from **Material components** `-> com.google.android.material` as you can see so, that's why you get the error.

Remember to update the `gradle` in the other `build.gradle` too:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

Comment: The same for the `TabLayout` > `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`. Adding the material dependency will solve the issue.

Comment: I have already ` implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'` in my classpath but it not works.

Comment: @DánielKis The question was for almost 2 years ago. However, If the provided solution didn't work for you, how about using Ask question of the website and opening another question with specific details?

Answer (score 40):

Don't forget to use `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` (or any `Theme.MaterialComponents.*.NoActionBar` really) as your parent `AppTheme` in `style.xml` ([source](https://material.io/develop/android/components/top-app-bars/#regular-top-app-bar)).

Comment: you saved my day. Thanks!!

Comment: You really saved my day and I couldn't see this information anywhere thank you so much!!!

Comment: @K.tas, see similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877777/android-material-chip-component-crashing-app-unable-to-inflate-xml, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957275/inflateexception-when-using-textinputlayout. A solution is similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

If you have added the above two conditions and it's still showing the error you can try a "LinearLayout" instead.

Answer (score 2):

Check your **/res/values/styles.xml** and set your theme to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

or similar