# Building AppBarLayout from com.google.android.material with Android.mk

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, android.mk

I have a system app that I am building using Android.mk. In my app layout, I want to use AppBarLayout from com.google.android.material. Here is the Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := ServiceTool
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := XXXXXX
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT:=false

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := androidx.fragment_fragment \
                                  androidx.appcompat_appcompat \
                                  androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout \
                                  androidx.legacy_legacy-support-v4 \

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android.hardware.light-V2.0-java \
                                open-csv \
                                classestool \
                                material-1.0.0 \
                                libdiagwrapper 


LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := AndroidManifest.xml

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := $(call all-subdir-java-files) \

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))


###################JARLIB
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
open-csv:libs/opencsv-4.6.jar \
classestool:libs/classes.jar \
material-1.0.0:libs/material-1.0.0.aar \
libdiagwrapper:libs/libdiagwrapper.jar \

   include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
###################
```

I added the file material-1.0.0.aar in a folder libs. It compiles well. However, when I am going to the Activity using the AppBarLayout in its layout, the app crash and I am getting this exception:

> 12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML
>   file line #11: Error inflating class
>   com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout 12-26 16:07:23.746
>   12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error
>   inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 12-26 16:07:23.746 12686
>   12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:467)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.motorolasolutions.servicetesttool.tests.ltetests.LteTestActivity.onCreate(LteTestActivity.java:206)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2932)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1817)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686
>   E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6746) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 12-26 16:07:23.746
>   12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   12-26 16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 12-26
>   16:07:23.746 12686 12686 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/material/R$style;

Where does it come from?

Comment: Refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688994/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-appbar-appbarlayout

Comment: I saw it. But they build their app using gradle. I build my app using Android.mk