# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout with AppCompat/Material theme

Tags: android, themes, android-xml, androidx, android-coordinatorlayout

I don't really know what exactly I am missing but I am getting the same inflate exception error even with an Appcomat theme.
logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aasha/com.example.aasha.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_good_things">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/message_box">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                    ....

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/chat_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/message_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/image_send_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image_add" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/message_type_box"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:hint="Type a message..."
                android:inputType="text" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/message_send_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message_send"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Aasha" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

    // androidx
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I searched and came across this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688994/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-appbar-appbarlayout), tried all the solutions that include:

**Invalidate Caches/Restart** with no luck. **Refactor** -> **Migrate to AndroidX** that says *No usages found for the project*.

I was puzzled and made a separate project with the same single layout that run without any issues but I am unable to differentiate and find the fault here. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` (or any `Theme.MaterialComponents.*.NoActionBar` really) as your parent AppTheme in `style.xml`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

change Gradle and material design to latest version

Comment: This was already mentioned in the given StackOverflow link. I already upgraded them to the latest. `com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0` and `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"`

Answer (score 1):

I was using SplashScreenApi which is from `androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen` library.

I knew that I have to call `installSplashScreen()` before `setContentView()` in my MainAcitivty() but what I didn't know was that it should be called even before any `viewBinding` initialization. It went somehow unnoticed for days for someone inexperienced like me. The app was running smoothly and everything was working well until any material design tag implementation.

Before:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        installSplashScreen()
        setContentView(binding.root)
        ...
}
```

After:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen()
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        ...
}
```

That was so stupid of me :(. It took me a while cause the logcat was always pointing the `setContentView()`